# GWT - Style CaptionPanel title as bold

Tags: gwt

What is the best way to style a CaptionPanel title as bold? I was hoping I could apply a CSS style. I'm currently doing:

```
CaptionPanel examplePanel = new CaptionPanel();
examplePanel.setCaptionHTML("<b>CaptionPanel Title</b>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The captions are translated in HTML `legend` elements. So use CSS to set `legend` elements font as bold.

If you want it on all captions, simply do :

```
legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But if you want it only for a specific `CaptionPanel`, you add a style name to it :

```
examplePanel.addStyleName("examplePanelStyleName");
```

and use the panel style name in the CSS :

```
.examplePanelStyleName legend {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: If I want to apply this on all captions, where exactly should the legend declaration be? I tried adding it to my own CSS file that is included in my GWT app, but it had no effect.

Comment: You can put it in any CSS file that your host page is pointing to.

Comment: You are correct. I'm honestly not sure how I had my syntax before, but I dropped it in my css today and it worked. Thanks.